# Splitting of character array into multiple smaller null terminated character array in C

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose we have a character array as,

```
char recvData[1024];
```

Now the data entered into the `recvData[1024]` is from the client using the function,

```
int nBytes = recvfrom(udpSocket, recvData, sizeof (recvData),
                      0, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage,
                      &addr_size);
```

The data received from the client code is present into recvData which is a character array.

We need to make 3 character arrays each one of them as null terminated:

First containing only the first byte of the content of `recvData`,

Second containing the next 6byte of the content of `recvData`,

Third containing the last 16byte of the content of `recvData`.

What shall we use to split the data from the recvData array if required in the above format.

Comment: Do the resulting arrays have to be null terminated? Do you keep the original array or will it be deleted?

Comment: Another question: Why do you allocate 1024 bytes when you only have 23 bytes of content?

Comment: We require to retain the original array..
Secondly yes we require all the resultant array as null terminated compulsorily..
No the buffer size in the application is required to be1024 only

Comment: Can you please edit the question, when you make additions? These additions are useful or even essential for the question. The girls that want to answer the question usually read the question. So it's best to have all requirements there. To make clear that you added requirements it's good behavior to mark the addition as ''Edit'' or ''Addtional Info'' or something else.

Comment: sure....did the corrections @harper

Comment: You changed the title instead of the question. This doesn't emphasizes neither the requirement not that you've edited the question after answers have been posted. -- If you want to make a correction, use the plural form of "array".

Comment: @harper added the required things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement for zero-termination rules out several more "hackish" solutions, like `memcpy()` recvData over `result_t`, or using a union -- we have to copy the fields individually.

After some polishing, turning magic numbers into macro constants and putting things into a function, that would look somewhat like this. You should assign more meaningful names to everything, of course.

```
#include <string.h>

#define FIRST_SIZE   1
#define SECOND_SIZE  6
#define THIRD_SIZE  16

struct result_t
{
    char first[ FIRST_SIZE + 1 ];
    char second[ SECOND_SIZE + 1 ];
    char third[ THIRD_SIZE + 1 ];
};

result_t handle_recvData( char * recvData )
{
    struct result_t result;

    memcpy( result.first, recvData, FIRST_SIZE );
    result.first[ FIRST_SIZE ] = '\0';

    memcpy( result.second, recvData + FIRST_SIZE, SECOND_SIZE );
    result.second[ SECOND_SIZE ] = '\0';

    memcpy( result.third, recvData + FIRST_SIZE + SECOND_SIZE, THIRD_SIZE );
    result.third[ THIRD_SIZE ] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you actually need them to be separate, or do you just need a nicer way of accessing the data.

If it's just about convenience, then:

```
const char first = recvData[0];
const char *second = &recvData[1];
const char *third = &recvData[7];
```

Just remember that the data will go away if you receive another packet. If you don't mind keeping the data together, but do want a copy of the buffer, then this may be better:

```
typedef struct Something {
    char first;
    char second[6];
    char third[16];
} Something;
...
Something data;
data.first = recvData[0];
memcpy(&data.second, &data[1], 6);
memcpy(&data.third, &data[7], 16);
```

If you however need to actually have 3 separate arrays, then:

```
char* something = malloc(the_size);
memcpy(something, &recvData[offset], the_size);
```

is what you do.

As mentioned in the comment this does not null-terminate the arrays. But you should be able to do that based on other answers.

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirement that the parts shall be zero-terminated. This wasn't part of the question but in a comment.

Comment: @harper: Which, to be fair, was added in a comment.

Comment: @viraptor, none of ur solution meets the requirement of null terminated subarrays.

Comment: @FarhanPatel That's why I added a note about it. SO is a service that will help you find a solution, not one that will write production quality code instead of you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all sub-arrays as null-terminated and the received data doesn't include these null-termination then you need to make copies of the arrays.

```
char recvData1[2];
char recvData2[7];
char recvData3[17];

memcpy(recvData1, recvData, 1);
recvData1[1] = '\0';
memcpy(recvData2, recvData+1, 6);
recvData2[6] = '\0';
memcpy(recvData3, recvData+7, 16);
recvData3[16] = '\0';

HandleReceiveParts(recvData1, recvData2, recvData3);
```